Why can we omit an article here?

This suffix is added to form new verbs denoting repetitive action


This suffix is added to a verb to create a new verb indicating repetitive action

Why isn't it "a repetitive action" and why can we even omit the article? And SHOULD we?

@ishtar Why would I even be allowed to interpret a random countable noun as uncountable? Can I do it at all times with all nouns?

It's always good to consult a dictionary before asking here. :)

In the sentences:

"This suffix is added to form new verbs denoting repetitive action."

"This suffix is added to a verb to create a new verb indicating repetitive action."


The phrase "repetitive action" is being used in a general sense, which is why there is no article (either "a" or "the") before it. When you're talking about a concept or category of things in general rather than a specific instance, English often omits the article. This is known as the zero article and is common when referring to uncountable nouns or abstract concepts like "repetitive action."
Why isn't it "a repetitive action"?
"Repetitive action" refers to the concept of an action being repeated, in a broad sense, not a specific or countable instance of repetition. Therefore, an article isn't necessary.
If you said "a repetitive action," you would be implying that you are referring to a specific example or instance of repetitive action, rather than the concept in general.
Omitting the article is correct.
